# Delete shortcut from desktop

Tags: c#, shortcut, delete-file

Well, it seems I am unable to delete a lnk file from the desktop.

```
string pathtoLink = "G:\\Personal Files\\Desktop\\" + appName + ".lnk";
File.SetAttributes(pathtoLink.Trim(), FileAttributes.Normal);
File.Delete(pathtoLink);

do
{
    File.Delete(pathtoLink);
} while (File.Exists(pathtoLink) == true);
```

The code above will enter the do loop - and keep looping indefinitely, it confirms the file exists at that location - but simply wont delete!  I can delete a shortcut from any other location no problems, and actual files from the desktop can be removed - but lnk files just wont shift.

Any ideas as to whats going on would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using a do loop? You can check if the file exists and delete it and surround it with try/catch to catch errors

Comment: I agree the loop is unnecessary, however it only explains why it is running forever and doesn't answer why it doesn't delete.

Comment: the loop is simply to confirm that the file is found but not deleted even after calling delete, it wont be included in any solution

Answer (score 2):

Those missing shortcuts are on the on the "All Users" desktop, it holds shortcuts that show up for every user of the system.

You can get the path to it via

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDesktopDirectory)
```

Comment: 7 years later, this one line just finished a solid few hours of trying to find out why my shortcut wasn't getting deleted. TY!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
var desktop = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
var app = appName + ".lnk";
File.Delete(Path.Combine(desktop, app));
```

Comment: Thanks, but no joy with that, i had just tried using combine but alas it makes no difference at all

Comment: I have noticed that although File.Exists tells me the file does exist, when i try to change attributes to normal (in case at some point the have been altered) - an exception is thrown - the file doesnt exist in the eyes of SetAttributes, but it does for File.Exists

Comment: The only other thing I can think of that it might be is a permissions issue. Have you tried running your application as an administrator?

Comment: Yes i sure have, and Ive created any number of normal shortcuts (manually and not in code), and SetAttributes still fails to see it or File.Delete to delete it - normal files fine, and shortcuts anywhere else but the desktop fine...

Comment: I have just tried creating a simple vbscript to get the desktop location and delete the shortcut - works no problems at all :-S

Comment: Have a look what `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);` actually returns, maybe it's returning the user Desktop path but the shortcut is in `Users\Public\Desktop`.

Comment: The Environment returns the correct path, I changed it to plain text as above just to make sure - the results are the same

Comment: Thanks folks, think i know the reason - if a shortcut is dead - i.e points to a file which is no longer there, C# just wont delete it - i tried making sure it was a valid shortcut and it deleted no problems

Comment: it seems when file.exists checks, it checks for the existance of the lnk file itself, file.delete checks for the existance of the target file - and if it doesnt exist, it wont delete the shortcut. unusual behaviour!

Comment: Weird behaviour but I'm glad you figured out what it was. You should post it as an answer for anyone else who finds this question in the future who might have the same issue